# ListPlot and AspectRatio

Tags: graphics, plotting

Here is a simple scenario

```
data = {{-0.5, 0.2}, {0.7, 0.1}, {1.4, -0.1}};
L0 = ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> {Black, PointSize[Large]}, 
Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 2}, {-1, 1}}]
```

which gives

[image]

My question is very simple: for the given plot range (it should not be changed) how can I get the two axes divisions (blue and red) equal in size?

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {{-0.5, 0.2}, {0.7, 0.1}, {1.4, -0.1}};
pr = {{-1.5, 4}, {-1, 1}};
L0 = ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> {Black, PointSize[Large]}, 
  Frame -> True, 
  AspectRatio -> First[1/Divide @@ (Differences /@ pr)], 
  PlotRange -> pr]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: OK, but what if I also want a square frame?

Comment: Yes, I want the blue and red distances shown in the plot to be equal.

Comment: I want a square plot like that posted in which the distance between the tickmarks of the x-axis (blue line) to be equal in length with the distance between the tickmarks of the y-axis (red line).

Comment: The ranges should be fixed as `PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 2}, {-1, 1}}`

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z No, what I meant is that the blue and red segments will be of equal length in the image, but they will represent different variable ranges.

Comment: Let me make it more clear. The red and blue lines correspond to 0.1 in both axes. I want to remain 0.1 keep the `PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 2}, {-1, 1}}` and the square plot. Is this possible?

Comment: So I have to change the plot range perhaps `PlotRange -> 2`?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z The condition for doing what you want is that `(xmax-xmin)==(ymax-ymin)` in the plotreange

Comment: I'm confused now! How do you edit `PlotRange` with the condition you mentioned?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z As a trivial example in your code `ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> {Black, PointSize[Large]}, Frame -> True,  AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 2}, {-1.5, 2}}]`

Comment: OK! I consider this question answered.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z Do you mind to come to chat a few minutes? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/wolfram-mathematica